# Web based application - HTML parsing

Tags: javascript, python, html, parsing

I'm working on a web based applcation, which loads the HTML content of an URL using the call made to http://www.whateverorigin.org/ This avoids the same origin policy violation

```
url = 'http://' + document.getElementById("urlText").value
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?', function(data){
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data.contents, 'text/html');
```

If I would need to extract the meaningful visible text from this html string, is there a way that I can do this like how beautifulsoup would do in python? I'm more a beginner to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in order to find and [iterate](http://api.jquery.com/each/) over the appropriate elements. Then you can decide what to print out - for example: show the text-node of visible items.
Here is a jsfiddle with a working script example: http://jsfiddle.net/w147o9f6/1/

```
<body>
    <div id="outputTexts">OUTPUT:</div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc;
var meaningfulTexts = [];
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com') + '&callback=?', function(data){
    doc = parser.parseFromString(data.contents, "text/html");

    var ELMS = $(doc).find("div, p, a, span");
    ELMS.each(function(index, element) {
        if(element.style.display != "none" && $(element).text() != "") {
            $("#outputTexts").append('<br>'+ element.tagName + ' - '+$(element).text());
            meaningfulTexts.push( $(element).text() );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I happen to see the css styling info as a part of the meaningul text. Is there a way I can remove them?

Comment: I checked my code against facebook and some other websites and it worked very well. When i checked it against google it showed those CSS codes (saying they sit inside a `span` tag). I don't know if it's a problem with my code or with google's site. Is `google.com` the website you intend to work with?

Comment: The web based application would be fetching the visible text from any site. $(doc).find("p, a"); I made this change. This seemed to work better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you need? The code below parses google.nl with the whateverorigin.org website and adds it to a div. If not, please try to explain what more you need!

**jQuery:**

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.nl') + '&callback=?', function(data){
        $('.result').html(data.contents);
    });
});`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qddekhnc/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffrey. I would need the meaningful text information as raw strings.